# Simple, powerful and stable Firmware for LinkSys WRT54GL

Tags: router, firmware, open-source

I have just bought a [Linksys WRT54G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series) router, which has the ability to load custom firmware.

As there are lots of them around the web, Can anyone recommend a FOSS simple, powerful and stable firmware package that also supports port forwarding?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Round up:

1. People love [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php) because it supports all kinds of cpus pretty well. It is sort of commercial. But the money aspect seems to keep them motivated.
2. People love [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/) because it is open and libre. Also it's more like running your own linux on a low-power box. It's got package-management even after it's up and running.
3. People love [FreeWRT](http://www.freewrt.org/trac/) because it's got a more accessible configurable build system.
4. People love [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) because it's red, has a nice interface, solid feature set, is straight forward, and can be caramelized for flavor.
5. People don't care about [HyperWRT](http://www.linksysinfo.co.uk/thibor/) anymore because it's kind of old now.
6. People actually [hate](http://sveasoftsucks.com/) [SveaSoft](http://www.sveasoft.com/modules/phpBB2/dlman.php?func=select_folder&folder_id=10) despite it being [first](http://www.pbs.org/cringely/pulpit/2004/pulpit_20040527_000456.html) (good read BTW).

Comment: +1 for a great overview of most current alternatives, and for a great writing style while answering well!

Answer (score 11):

I'm running [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) on my WRT54GL and I love it. It doesn't quite have all the features of DD-WRT but it been rock-solid and still has all the essential features, of course including port forwarding. It has a nice AJAX interface that can show you your bandwidth usage, has good  QoS controls, lets you control tons of aspects of your wireless (many types of security, antenna power, etc). I'd definitely recommend it.

Comment: +1 Tomato, fully agree. Was the first custom firmware I tried on my WRT54GL. Never seen any reason to try anything else.

Comment: Another Tomato fan here.  I've tried a few different firmware, but tomato does everything I need, and better than most.  Also I found the stock firmware wouldn't correctly reconnect a pppoe connection, tomato does this flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.dd-wrt.com/

You can see your router in the list of compatible routers at:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/dd-wrt/hardware.html

Comment: Some people find this to be much too commercially oriented to be the right answer.

Comment: That is true. I learned about a few others out there from the other responces thanks to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/) and [FreeWRT](http://www.freewrt.org/trac/) are the leaders of the pack at the moment. [FreeWRT](http://www.freewrt.org/trac/) being designed to be more user-friendly than the others.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [X-wrt](http://x-wrt.org/install.html). It's Open-wrt with a graphical interface. The current release of Open-Wrt (and therefore X-wrt) is Kamikaze.  Also woth considering is [freifunk]. It's Open-wrt White Russian with an interface and controls designed for a community mesh.